# speed/duplex mismatch between 1000Mb and 100Mb full duplex

Tags: speed

need your thoughts on this, i have a switch that runs on 1000mb Full duplex and a firewall with 100Mb Full duplex, is there a possibility traffic wont pass through?

Comment: I am curious are you solving a real problem or is this more of a theoretical question? Either way could you provide a little more background?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

You don't give a lot of detail, but you do have a specific question.  Yes it is entirely possible that traffic won't pass between a 1000/Full interface and a 100/Full interface.

While many 1Gig connections will have the capability to run at 100/Full, there are also a fair number that do not.  For instance, most 1Gig transceiver hardware will not work at 100/Full.

I don't know which make/model of switch you have, but on most enterprise class switches there is a command that will give you all sorts of details on the the features and capabilities of the port.  For example, on a Cisco switch you would use a command similar to ***show interfaces capabilities module [module number]*** command and you would get output similar to the below:

```
GigabitEthernet3/1
  Model:                 WS-X4306-GB-Gbic
  Type:                  1000BaseSX
  Speed:                 1000
  Duplex:                full
  Auto-MDIX:             no
  Trunk encap. type:     802.1Q,ISL
  Trunk mode:            on,off,desirable,nonegotiate
  Channel:               yes
  Broadcast suppression: percentage(0-100), hw
  Flowcontrol:           rx-(off,on,desired),tx-(off,on,desired)
  VLAN Membership:       static, dynamic
  Fast Start:            yes
  CoS rewrite:           yes
  ToS rewrite:           yes
  Inline power:          no
  SPAN:                  source/destination
  UDLD:                  yes
  Link Debounce:         no
  Link Debounce Time:    no
  Port Security:         yes
  Dot1x:                 yes
  Maximum MTU:           9198 bytes (Jumbo Frames)
  Multiple Media Types:  no
  Diagnostic Monitoring: N/A
  Queuing:               rx-(N/A), tx-(1p3q1t, Sharing/Shaping)
```

This shows an example of an interface that will not be able to communicate with your 100/Full firewall.

In addition, your interfaces may also not support Auto-MDIX.  In this case, you may or not need a crossover cable to connect the devices depending on the hardware.  Having the wrong cable will prevent the interfaces from establishing a connection.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: The switch should auto-negotiate down to 100-full on its own.

Long answer: If the switch for some whatever reason refuses to properly auto-negotiate with the firewall (or vice-versa) you may need to force the switch interface to 100-Full. This can actually happen in a few scenarios.

Some older firewalls and older routers (various makes/models) have interfaces that only talk at 100-Full - they won't properly auto-negotiate with other equipment. As a result, you sometimes need to force the speed/duplex on the other equipment (in this case, the switch).

When you hook them up, take a look at the switch and firewall error logs - if you see speed/duplex mismatch errors and/or other errors that increment frequently, go ahead and force the switch to 100-full.

No errors? Congratulations, that means your equipment is properly auto-negotiating! Happy networking.

Answer (score 0):

The big question is are we talking twisted pair or Fiber?

With twisted pair nearly everything supports autonegotiation and unless your equipment is very old autonegotiation works just fine. Occasionally you may find a crossover cable is needed. Be aware that mixing autonegotiation with manually set full duplex is likely to lead to a duplex mismatch. You should only use manual speed/duplex if you have problems with autonegotiation and if you do use it you should use it on both ends of the link.

Fiber on the other hand is a mess of diffent incompatible standards. 1Gbps fiber standards are not compatible with 100Mbps fiber standards. Most 1Gbps fiber gear uses pluggable transcievers and it may be possible to get a 100Mbps transceiver that is compatible with your 1Gbps switch and is compatible with the fiber standard used by your 100Mbps device. Alternatively if the gigabit switch also has twisted pair ports it may be possible to use a media converter to go from 100 Mbps fiber to 100 Mbps twisted pair.